# Why does IPEndPoint take an Int64 and an Int32 as parameters?

Tags: c#, .net

Why not have chosen to use an UInt32 (for the IP) and an UInt16 (for the port)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does .NET use int instead of uint in certain classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782629/why-does-net-use-int-instead-of-uint-in-certain-classes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unsigned integers are not [**CLS** compliant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfa3fa08.aspx). As such *many* languages does not support them and they are avoided, whenever possible, in the .NET base class libraries (BCL).

See also: [Why are unsigned int's not CLS compliant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325/why-are-unsigned-ints-not-cls-compliant)